# Popup message for Smtp email is sent successfully in try block

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, smtpclient

I am using SmtpClient to send email by submit button. Email is sent succesfully after Submit clicked, meanwhile i want to inform user(popup window) whether email is sent succesfully or not but i couldn`t find a proper way to achieve it. Please check my code below:

```
@using System.Net.Mail;
@{
ViewBag.Title = @Resources.Common.AppName;
}


if (IsPost)
{
    var memberCode = Request["memberCode"];
    var memberNo = Request["memberNo"];
    var msgSub = "title:" + ViewBag.PromotionFeedTitle;
    var msgBody = "Member Code: "+memberCode+"\nMember Contact: "+memberNo;

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {

        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        msg.To.Add("xxx@xxx.net");
        msg.Subject = msgSub;

        //Create message body in HTML
        msg.Body = msgBody;

        // Send the email
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            //send succeed

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //send failed

        }
    }   
}
```

**Html Form:**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return terms(); ">
 <div>
  <fieldset>
   <table>
   <h4 id="popuptitle" style="direction=left; color: Aqua;">
   申请优惠：@ViewBag.Title
   <tr><td>
   MemberCode：
   </td><td>
   <input id="memberCode" autocomplete="off" type="text" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" onkeypress="return alpha(event)" name="memberCode" style="color: Black;" required>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>
   MemberNo：
   </td>
   <td>
   <input id="memberNo" autocomplete="off" type="number" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" OnKeyPress="return CheckNumericKeyInfo(event.keyCode, event.which)" name="memberNo" style="color: Black;" required/>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="agree" class="largerCheckbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="1" />
   </td>
   <td>
   Checkbox
   </td></tr>
   </table>
   </fieldset>
   </div>
   </form>
```

**Submit button div:**

```
<div class="divbtns" style="width: 95%;">
<button id="sbutton" class="button" type="submit" data-theme="t" form="form1">
Send</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** All above is in View page not behind-code. I am trying to achieve success message within try/catch block. Thank you for helps.

Comment: What is the **problem** with your code?

Comment: i want to popup a successful message after message is sent. thanks for concern.

Comment: Have you had a look at [jQueryDialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @Izzy yes actually i want to use jQueryDialog but i have no idea how to invoke it from try{} block

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a popup, there are two approaches:
-when you return View, at client-side you can show a pop-up to inform user like:

```
$(function(){alert("Your mail was sent!");});
```

-you can use ajax to submit your form and then show a pop-up when you receive response from server

```
$.Ajax({
    ....
    success: function(data){alert("Your mail was sent!");}
});
```

Comment: thanks, can you please demonstrate or detail it some more, i am quite new in c#

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code, you can write a response that is returned to the client using

```
Response.Write("Success");
```

or

```
Response.Write("Failed");
```

Then the client can read the response of the Ajax-call and determine whether the message was successfully sent. You can then show a message using the `alert()` function.

You would have to perform an Ajax-call instead of a page submit though. Which would look something like this using jQuery:

```
                $.ajax({
                    // ajax options
                    success: function(data, status, xhttp)
                    {     
                        if (data == 'Success') {
                          alert('Yay! It worked!');
                        }
                        else {
                          alert("Oh noes!!!");
                        }                      
                    }
                });
```